# What is the htaccess equivalent of <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8>

Tags: .htaccess, utf-8

What is the htacces equivalent to `meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"`? Yslow says i should put this in my htacces. I'm on appache server.

Ok seen here I have I think an answer. Which code is appropriate though? I only have html extensions on my site. http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/setting-charset-in-htaccess.html

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .html
```

vs

```
AddType 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' html
```

vs

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

vs

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 2):

The first one, `AddCharset`, tells the server that files ending in `.html` should be said to be encoded in UTF-8.

The second gives the full `Content-Type` for HTML files, including both the MIME type and charset. This shouldn't be necessary, since Apache should already be configured to serve `.html` files as `text/html`.

The third, `AddDefaultCharset`, sets the default character set for all file types, not just HTML. So, for instance, text documents, XML documents, stylesheets, and the like will be served with a `UTF-8` character set listed. This is what I would recommend; you should be saving all of your documents in UTF-8 by default anyhow, and so even if all of your documents are HTML now, this will keep the correct character set configured for other types of files if you add them later.

The last is not an Apache configuration; it's the actual header that should be sent along with your documents if you set one of the above options. You can check the headers that were sent in Firebug on Firefox, or various developer tools that other browsers offer. You should always have a `Content-Type:` header, and if your text is encoded in UTF-8, it should always specify `charset=UTF-8`.

Note that the `meta` tag is not required if you set the charset appropriately via the headers. It is still nice to have the `meta` tag if you are going to view the files locally, without a web server; in that case, there is nothing to set the header, so the browser needs to fall back toe the `meta` tag. But for this purpose, you can use the shorter and simpler `meta` tag: `<meta charset=utf-8>`. This abbreviated form was formally introduced in HTML5, but browsers have actually supported it for much longer, and it's compatible with all modern browsers, even back to IE 6.

Comment: Many thanks Brian for your detailed answer. After posting I came across this code...                                                                     <filesMatch "\.(htm|html|css|js|php)$">
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
DefaultLanguage en-US
</filesMatch>
It's seemed perfect to me. But if what you say is true I should do away with the filesMatch because that code refers to all file extensions??? Also, is it  good idea to include the language too? Thanks! Sorry I can't use return button on my iPad or it just posts the answer. So I can't format my answer.

Comment: I can't find any documentation on that serving all file types. Do you know of any links saying that?

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is the rewrite engine (in this case, matching no-extension URLs):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ $1 [type=text/html]
```